# Raising/Setting WIN32 event

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, winapi, command-prompt

I created a small Windows application that creates an event and waits for it to be triggered, using the `CreateEvent()` and `WaitForSingleObject()` Win32 APIs.

I also created another application that is used to trigger the event that was created by the previously mentioned application, using the `SetEvent()` API.

They work well with each other, but I am looking to simplify how the triggering is done. Is there a way via command prompt or PowerShell to trigger an event that was created by a Win32 C++ application? I want to remove the need for maintaining an additional application.

I've tried looking at what PowerShell provides, but have not had much luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way via command prompt or PowerShell to trigger an event that was created by a Win32 C++ application?

PowerShell scripts have access to .NET classes, so you can use the [`EventWaitHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle?view=net-7.0) class to open and trigger the C++ app's event.

```
$SetEventName = 'MyEvent'

function Signal-SetEvent {
    $SetEventObject = [System.Threading.EventWaitHandle]::OpenExisting( $SetEventName )
    $SetEventObject.Set()
}
```

Comment: This did the trick just as I wanted. Thanks!